# Reduce the DOM search frequency in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, find

I'm in the process of getting rid of Jquery from a small project and re-writing the script with vanilla js. In the current code there's a jquery implementation to search a DOM element and then use jquery 'find'to search specific elements within the element.

```
var ImageCapture ={
    cacheDom : function(){
        this.form = $('#drawingBoard');
        this.saveBtn = this.form.find('#saveBtn');
        this.image = this.form.find('#image');
        this.results = this.form.find('#results');
    }
}
```

I've converted the above Jquery code into vanilla js like below.

```
var ImageCapture ={
        cacheDom: function () {
            this.form = document.getElementById('drawingBoard');
            this.saveBtn = this.form.querySelector('#saveBtn');
            this.image = this.form.querySelector('#image');
            this.results = this.form.querySelector('#results');
        }
    }
```

The new implementation seem to be working fine but I wanted to be sure if it's the correct way of replacing the Jquery implementation using vanilla JS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, it's fine. Nothing really wrong with it, or that could be improved.

Comment: Looks ok as for me. You can also replace `getElementById` with `querySelector` for consistency

Comment: Since you're using only IDs as selector, getElementById is slightly more performant than querySelector. If that matters, you might want to switch (although in reality there's so little between them, you likely won't notice any difference unless you're doing a LOT of operations). Other than that, it all looks fine.

Comment: `getElementById` it's the fastest way to select an element: https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector . Looks good anyway!!

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. 

Does this implementation avoid the need to do multiple DOM checks though? 

In the Jquery implementation, DOM search is done only once and the rest of the elements are searched using the .find method.

Comment: @Jayonline no, `elem.find` is not similar to `elem.querySelector`. According to the documentation I've read, `elem.querySelector` checks *the whole dom*, and then tries to see if the element it finds is a descendent of `elem`, rather than the expected jQuery behavior.

Comment: Cheers for that insight,@TKoL - Is there any similar implementation in javascript that doesn't require multiple dom checks? 
Many thanks!

Comment: @Jayonline as far as I know, there is no replacement for `jQuery.find`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made two jsfiddles to show you a subtle difference in behavior between plain js querySelectorAll and jQuery selectors. You would naturally expect them to behave the same but they do not.

Here is the plain js version: https://jsfiddle.net/a81e2do3/

Here is jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/a81e2do3/1/

In short, if you have this html:

```
div#a > div#b > div#c
```

if you have a plain JS element node object of #b, you can do `b.querySelector('#a #c')` and successfully select div#c, but you cannot do that in jQuery (which imo makes more sense the jQuery way).

Comment: Thanks very much for this @TKol!